# Dimensions of $\phi$ in scalar field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, dimensional-analysis

On Srednicki page 90-91 (in printed edition) he derives that $$[\phi] = \frac{1}{2}(d-2) \tag{12.10}$$ from $${\cal L}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi -\frac{1}{2}m^{2}\phi^{2} -  \sum_{n=3}^{N}\frac{1}{n!}g_{n}\phi^{n}$$ and the fact that $[\partial^\mu] = +1$ in units of mass. Can someone please elaborate how he gets to $$[\phi] = \frac{1}{2}(d-2)~?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He uses that the action is dimensionless so that
\begin{align}
[ d^d x \left(\partial\varphi\right)^2]  &=  0 \\
&=[d^d x]+2[\partial\varphi]\\ 
&= -d +2 + 2[\varphi]
\end{align}
using that $[dx]=-1$ and $[\partial\varphi] = [\partial] + [\varphi] = 1+[\varphi]$.

This gives $[\varphi] = (d-2)/2$